# Task Starting multiple times?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, task-parallel-library

I have a series of tasks that I want to run regularly... every x seconds or minutes.

I am using a dispatchtimer to fire when that interval is reached.  Once reached and the timer ticks I have a series of tasks to run that I await one after the other.

Here is part of the code... trimmed for simplicity:

```
private async void timerAutoSync_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        //Task[] tasks = new Task[2];


        try
        {
            MainMessage("AutoSync | Looking for items to sync... ");

            timerAutoSync.IsEnabled = false;

            Sync.FeedbackEvent += sync_FeedbackEvent;


            // Run enabled tasks...
            if (!autosyncStopRequested && Properties.Settings.Default.AutoSyncOptionSyncCustomers)
            {
                // New 
                SyncProcessRunning(true, "Customers");

                Task<bool> tCustomerSync = Sync.SyncCustomersToWebMaster("", Properties.Settings.Default.msSQLConnectionString.ToString(), WPFCommon.This_Sync_Node_ID);
                tasks.Add(tCustomerSync);
                bool tCustomerSyncResult = tCustomerSync;
                MainMessage("After Customer Sync await | Autosync Timer Status: " + timerAutoSync.IsEnabled.ToString());
            }

    // Other tasks for products, inventory, etc. follow the same pattern 

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                    {
                        string memoryBefore = String.Format("Memory used before collection: {0:N0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
                        MainMessage(memoryBefore);
                        IcsLogEntries.WriteXmlLogEntry(memoryBefore);
                        Task.Delay(5000);

                        // Try to keep things clean.. 
                        GC.Collect();

                        string memoryAfter = String.Format("Memory used After collection: {0:N0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
                        MainMessage(memoryAfter);
                        IcsLogEntries.WriteXmlLogEntry(memoryAfter);
                        Task.Delay(5000);

                        timerAutoSync.IsEnabled = true;

                        MainMessage("AutoSync | Sync Complete. " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                        SyncProcessRunning(false, "");

                    });
                });
```

So this runs nicely, awaits as it should, hits the WhenAll to let me clean up and turn the timer back on which will wait x period of time (30 seconds right now) and then run the same series of tasks again.

HOWEVER in production it seems to kick off each of my tasks run fine ... leave it around somewhere and then run 2 of the same tasks on the next pass of the dispatch timer... the following round of the timer it runs 3 of the same tasks... etc.  Adding multiples of the same task at each tick of the timer...

I know this because of the log files I create in the Sync.* tasks... I can see multiples in a row where only one should be.

I'm wondering if I should dispose of the tasks in the WhenAll.ContinueWith section...

From my logs, it does not seem that the dispatch timer tick has multiple instances running.  Just the Sync.* tasks.

I'm confused.

I'm going to add this in my WhenAll.Continue secton:

```
                        foreach (Task t in tasks)
                        {
                            t.Dispose();
                        }
```

Other suggestions?

BTW:  I can't make this happen in debugging mode...

Comment: Just because you're using WPF for your UI it doesn't mean the question is WPF related. I don't see anything WPF specific in your question so please consider removing the tag... otherwise why not add your IDE tag, your OS tag and so on?

Comment: @pStan: The problem is not in the code you posted. Based on your description, I suspect that additional dispatcher timer instances are being created with each run. P.S. Don't use `ContinueWith` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`; you can just `await Task.WhenAll(tasks); string memoryBefore = ...`

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I've been trying to keep up with your blog post and use the best methods.  I'll pull out the Dispatcher.Invoke.  I think I have found the problem.   This line:  Sync.FeedbackEvent += sync_FeedbackEvent;   ran every time the dispatchtimer ticked... that seemed to cause my feedback event to fire multiple times ... increasing exponentially... moved it and hooked up only once.  We are good.  Thanks again for your help !!!!!